# Nginx – Rewrite rule madness

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to redirect links that look like:

http://example.com/dev/some_project

to their physical location:

http://example.com/dev/some_project/some_project.php

In order to achieve this, I came up with this following rule set:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @folderless-php;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
}


location @folderless-php {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ "${uri}/${basename}.php";
}
```

This, however, will for some reason just invoke an internal server error.

So I tried changing it to:

```
location / {
    set $folderless "${uri}/${basename}.php";
    try_files $uri $uri/ $folderless;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
}
```

This seemed to work with `curl`, but when I tried this in any browser, I was just offered to download the file that I tried to access, to my astonishment.

What causes this behavior? Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You are being given a download as you haven't told Nginx how to handle PHP files. You need to set up the fast-cgi parameters to something like:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_read_timeout 60000;
    fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/site$fastcgi_script_name;
    include         fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: Nginx already knows how to handle PHP files, since I configured that when I set up Nginx a while ago. Going to http://example.com/index.php works flawlessly (without being offered a download), but my rewrite does not.